# Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost'

Tags: windows, svn

I installed the Subversion package version 1.7 on windows 7 operating system using admin account

I created the depository with the following command: `svnadmin create "c:\svn_repository"`

I modified the `svnserve.conf` and passwd files : `anon-access = read`, `auth-access = write`, and `password-db = passwd`

I installed the Subversion as a windows service and I started it using the following commands:

```
sc create svnserver binpath= "C:\Program Files (x86)\Subversion\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r c:\svn_repository" DisplayName= "Subversion" depend= tcpip start= auto
```

I also setted the variable `SVN_EDITOR` to : `set SVN_EDITOR=c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe`

The problem I faced is when I invoke the following command :

```
svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproject
```

I receive the following error :

```
svn: E200002: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://localhost'
svn: E200002: C:\svn_repository\conf\svnserve.conf:19: Option expected
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

check the svnserve.conf for whitespace at the beginning of the line for  each option you specified (in your case, check line 19 of svnserve.conf, if you have a white space before that line, remove it)

Comment: Excatly the problem was the whitespace at the begining of options. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`-r c:\svn_repository"` and `svnadmin create c:\svn_repository` are incompatible

-r define **common root of repositories** and can't be repository per se